# regex use of D\*

Tags: javascript, regex-look-ahead

what is the need of adding  \D* in this question answer
Use lookaheads in the pwRegex to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long, and have two consecutive digits.

```
let sampleWord = "bana12";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{6})(?=\D*\d{2})/; //  this line
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
```

i tried without adding \D* in the code but it didn't work, why?

Comment: [regexper](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%3F%3D%5Cw%7B6%7D%29%28%3F%3D%5CD*%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%2F)

Comment: That regex matches `ab12c3`, but not `3c21ba`. That can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `\D*`, the second condition would start the match from the position of the two digits, not from the first char.

This will not match:

```
/(?=\w{6})(?=\d{2})/
testTest12tes
```

This will match:

```
/(?=\w{6})(?=\d{2})/
testTest12test
```

That's because the second example satisfies both condition simultaneously (the second condition `(?=\d{2})` without 4 other characters after the two-digits number cause the first condition `(?=\w{6})` to fail as `12tes` is not a valid 6-character long string. But, when we use `12test`, both conditions are evaluated correctly.

The use of `\D*` let the second condition consider also the characters before the two-digit number, automatically confirming also the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `(?=\w{6})(?=\D*\d{2})` means:

From the *current position*, assert that directly to the right there are 6 word characters AND optional non digit characters followed by 2 digits.

---

If you must use a regex to "match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long" then this is not a good pattern.

It will not match `ab1c23` which is 6 characters and contains 2 consecutive digits. The reason is because `\D` can not cross matching the single digit `1` in this case to get to the `23`

If you are using `.test()` you can anchor the regex to the start of the string using `^`, use a single lookahead to assert 6 word characters and then match 2 digits:

```
^(?=\w{6}).*\d\d
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rlp4Cv/1).

```js
const regex = /^(?=\w{6}).*\d\d/;
[
  "bana12",
  "abc123",
  "ab1c23",
  "banan1",
  "airplanes",
  "astronaut",
  "123",
  "1234"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
)
```